# Proving that $Z_t=g(X_t)$ is a martingale if and only if $\mathbb{E}(Z_t|Z_s)=Z_s \ \forall t>s \geq 0$. ($X_t$ Markov)

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I want to prove the next property:

Let $X_t$  be a Markov process (so $\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{E}(X_t|X_s)$ where $\mathcal{F_t}=\sigma(X_s, s\leq t)$).

Suppose that $Z_t=g(X_t)$ where $g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$  is an injective function. Then, $Z_t$ is a martingale adapted to  $ \mathcal{F}_t $ if and only if $\mathbb{E}(Z_t|Z_s)=Z_s \  \forall t>s \geq 0$.

So by starting with $\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{E}(X_t|X_s)$ I have to prove that $\mathbb{E}(Z_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{E}(Z_t|Z_s)$.

I do not know how to start, so any  hint or reference will be very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(X_t)$ is a Markov process, $\mathbb{E}(g(X_t)\mid {\cal F}_s)=P_{s,t}g(X_s)$ where $P_{s,t}$ is the transition kernel. 
Therefore $\mathbb{E}(g(X_t)\mid {\cal F}_s)$ is measurable with respect to 
$\sigma(X_s)=\sigma(Z_s).$

Comment: Could you elaborate a litte bit more your answer, please? I am not used to work with concepts like the Markov transition Kernel.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, what do you need to know? By the way, your comment above contradicts the final sentence of your original post ;)

Comment: Yes, it does a little bit :)  The thing is that I don´t know how the transition Kernel works, there is not some more intuitive way to prove it ?

Comment: Is there any book in which this property is demonstrated? I don´t find anything...

Comment: In my opinion, you will not find this exercise in any book and you will not be able to solve it without understanding the Markov transition kernel. To start, it may be useful for you to recall the *definition* of a Markov process.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The definition I use is the next: $X_t$ is Markov if  $\mathbb{E}(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{E}(X_t|X_s)$. However, I would work trying to understand the transition Kernel and get to understand your indication.

Comment: Careful, that is **not** the definition of a Markov process.

Comment: It´s not one of the equivalent definitions?